# Unable to Alter Table or run sp_changedbowner on SQL Server 2019, logged in as SA

Tags: sql-server

Issue arose when databases were moved from SQL Server 2008 Express to SQL Server 2019 Express (v15.0.2070). Existing MRP application uses the moved databases on SQL Server 2019 Express after move and the apps run fine (adding, deleting, updating records).

Users using Excel (vbs) to access MRP data, also have no issues after move. Security objects were exported from SQL Server 2008 and imported into SQL Server 2019, backed up databases were restored to 2019. Compatibility level was not changed.

Several SQL scripts that ran fine on SQL Server 2008 now no longer run in SQL Server 2019 Express. SQL scripts alter tables to remove constraints for primary keys, update/fix data, then restore constraints.

Using SSMS (18.5.1), logged in as 'SA', I cannot alter table.

```
USE PRODUCTION
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Additional_Charge] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Job_on_AddlChg];
```

This fails with:

> Msg 1088, Level 16, State 13
> Cannot find the object "Additional_Charge" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

Also tried:

```
USE PRODUCTION
GO
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

This fails with:

> Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1.
> Cannot find the database 'PRODUCTION', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

From within SSMS, I can successfully select table `Additional_Charge` and edit it. The table is visible from Object Explorer.

I'm stumped, because as user SA, I don't understand why this isn't working. Did some permissions/rights fail to get restored/assigned during the migration? I checked the ownership of the databases and 'SA' owns them.

Comment: So you have an `sa` user in your database? That seems unusual. Is the `sa` user linked to the `sa` SQL Server login?

Comment: To clarify, I ran the tests and also tried to run the scripts logged in as 'SA'. There is no user account 'SA', in the individual databases.